# Why in Haskell, "Char" is represented by "\" symbol? Designed like this?

Tags: haskell, char, representation

```
Prelude> maxBound::(Bool,Int,Char)
(True,9223372036854775807,'\1114111')
Prelude> minBound::Char
'\NUL'
```

Why it's showing \NUL,  not a number like '\1114111'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Char` in Haskell represents Unicode symbols.

The first symbol has code `0` and defined in Unicode as [`NULL`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm). It is also a part of ASCII character set and everyone associates `\NUL` (as well as `\NULL`) with `0`.

The largest possible symbol has code `1114111` (`0x10ffff`) and defined as [`Noncharacter`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10ffff/index.htm). There are at least two Unicode symbols named `Noncharacter`: the second is [`0x10fffe`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10fffe/index.htm).